# How insert multiple rows to same table at the same time in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a **products** table and a **pr_tags** table.I want to add my products tags to pr_tags table.
PrTag model:

```
protected $table = 'pr_tags';
protected $fillable=['pr_tags','slug','product_id'];
```

I thought that i can do this with loop in contoller,but my loop not working correctly.

```
    try {
            $request->merge(['pr_prev_price' => $request->pr_last_price, 'slug' => $slug, 'seller_id' => Auth::id()]);
            $newProduct = Product::create($request->except('pr_tags'));

            $last_id = $newProduct->id;

            $countTags = count(explode(',', $request->pr_tags));
            for ($i = 0; $i < $countTags; $i++) {
                $splitedTags = explode(',', $request->pr_tags);
                $tag_slug = str::slug($splitedTags[$i]);
                $request->merge(['product_id' => $last_id, 'slug' => $tag_slug, 'pr_tags' => $splitedTags[$i]]);
                PrTag::create($request->only('pr_tags', 'slug', 'product_id'));
            }
            return response(['processStatus' => 'success', 'processTitle' => 'Success', 'processDesc' => 'Congratulations , product added successfully !']);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response(['processStatus' => 'error', 'processTitle' => 'Error', 'processDesc' => 'Product could not added !', 'error' => $e]);
        }
```

First of all i am creating my new table for products table and i am getting the new id(**$last_id**) of new product for store in my **pr_tags** table.Than my loop begin.My products tags(**$request->pr_tags**) comes as 'tag,tag2,tag3...'.I am exploding this tags for store these in their rows as:

```
|id|tag |slug |product_id|
------------------------
|1 |tag |tag  |1         |
|2 |tag2|tag2 |1         |
|3 |tag3|tag3 |1         |
..........................
```

But this loop only gives me one row,not as i expected. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered batch insertion?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better in your case to have a Many-to-Many relationship between your Products and your Tags, using pivot table?